# Segmentation fault (core dumped) no scanf de dados da matriz

Tags: c, matriz, scanf

Esse seguinte pedaço de código da erro, não lê os dados do usuário para alocar na matriz 5x2, não consigo encontrar o problema

```
 int linha=0, coluna=0;
    int matriz[5][2];


    for(linha=0;linha < 5; linha++){
        for(coluna=0;coluna < 2; coluna++){
        scanf("%i", matriz[linha][coluna]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: `scanf("%i", &matriz[linha][coluna]);`  ou `scanf("%d", &matriz[linha][coluna]);`

Comment: Ah sim, é verdade, que falta de atenção a minha. Muito obrigado